# Log messages to JUnit console

Tags: java, junit, intellij-idea

Sometimes as I'm writing unit tests it's useful to have log messages, and see them when I run the tests, in the JUnit console (I'm using IntelliJ, but I think Eclipse is very similar).

The problem is that System.out.println doesn't work.  Does anyone have any tips on how to print log messages to the JUnit console?

Comment: Netbeans and Eclipse show's System.out.println messages. Can you post some sample code?

Answer (score 16):

You should select the test in the tree on the left to see its output in the console on the right:

[image]

Comment: The Android unit tester probably runs in a different environment, so the IDE can not see the logs.  Try looking at the log files of your Android emulator or device.

Comment: It does  not work for android, I see only logs in logcat, how to display it in test console?

Comment: This works for the new Android JUnit tests (run on local machine, no Android context) but unfortunately doesn't work when running android *instrumented* tests on a real or emulated android device

Comment: Doesn't work for IntelliJ

Answer (score -1):

use log tab of run/configuration in intellij idea

http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/run-debug-configuration-junit.html